# Mkmapview Half page curl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make half curl animation in iPhone like the maps app ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863049/how-to-make-half-curl-animation-in-iphone-like-the-maps-app)

I need to implement half page curl in map view exactly like Google map app. I implement `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`, `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` it does not work out exactly like Google map.

Comment: Check the following SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133644/iphone-sdk-4-half-curl-page-transition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863049/how-to-make-half-curl-animation-in-iphone-like-the-maps-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FDCatalog](https://github.com/FairfaxMobile/FDCatalog).

[image]

Comment: i need exactly like that.but fdcatalog source code not working(FDCurlViewControl missing)

Comment: Hi, get the two missing files from here: https://github.com/FairfaxMobile/FDCurlViewControl

Comment: This doesn't mimic Apple's Maps app exactly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406125/1148702 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406056/1148702 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406104/1148702 for my solution to this problem.

Comment: FDCatalog have some problem with curl button it will delaying every touches after touches....