# Implementing page curl feature

Tags: iphone, ios, page-curl

I am creating a map application similar to the iphone map app. I need to have the page curl feature, same as that in the map app. Need help in this case.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2863049/1081831, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6001830/1081831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that it's actually quite easy for a partial page curl:

As stated in previous answers to similar questions, you simply need to present a modal view controller with `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` :

> When the view controller is presented, one corner of the current view
>   curls up to reveal the modal view underneath. On dismissal, the curled
>   up page unfurls itself back on top of the modal view. A modal view
>   presented using this transition is itself prevented from presenting
>   any additional modal views.
>
> This transition style is supported only if the parent view controller
>   is presenting a full-screen view and you use the
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen modal presentation style. Attempting to
>   use a different form factor for the parent view or a different
>   presentation style triggers an exception.

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses Private APIs for partial page curl. If you want a partial page curl animation like in Maps app, you can use an animation of type:

```
animation.type = @"pageCurl";
```

If you are not targeting for the app store, you can probably use this. To apply a partial page curl yourself would be a tedious task and would require advanced Core Animation and Open GL stuff.

But, if you just want a normal full page curl, not a partial one, you can use this documented method:

```
+ (void)setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition forView:(UIView *)view cache:(BOOL)cache;
```

and set the transition as:

```
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp/UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
```